# Update to Xcode 8 make new warning in storyboard

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, xcode8

After I update to Xcode 8 all my story board viewcontroler
remove sizeClass √ and all the view with warning.

this image is example :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set All the Screen According to selected Device. Click on warning and Fix misplacement[image]

After XCode Updation it Show Pop Up like This When You Open Your StoryBoard In Xcode 8 First Time

[image]

Comment: before the update to Xcode 8 I don't have any warning

Comment: yeah it's due to select UI according to Device

Comment: ok after i chose iPhone 6s it still no contain all the view like the image i post in the question.

Comment: in the xcdoe 7 project all my viewcontroler in storyboard create with size class.

Comment: you can see if you change to "Open In " to Xcode 7 and save and open again in Xcode 8.

Comment: its works after i check the √ "Apply to all view in container"